# if a class width is 100% then hide two different divs

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have a class called

```
.fp-slidesContainer
```

if this class has

```
width=100%
```

then I want two divs: #left and #right to be hidden.
Any help?

I'm stuck here.

```
toggle();
window.onresize = function() {
    toggle();
}

function toggle() {
if (.fp-slidesContainer = 100%) {
    document.getElementById('left').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('right').style.display = 'none';
}
else {
    document.getElementById('left').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('right').style.display = 'block';
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to be a simple since IE & other browser treat it differently.
You can use `currentStyle` for IE and `getComputedStyle` for rest of browsers. But the catch is value is returned in pixel

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
function toggle() {
var _m = document.getElementsByClassName('fp-slidesContainer')[0];
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(_m,null).getPropertyValue("width"))
//Rest of your code
}
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/efnys1az/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip @user2181397, I just tried to work around your jsFiddle but it seems it's not working :/